# R: Using Inverse Distance Weighting with the mapply function

Tags: r, spatial-statistics

I would like to find what are the optimal power parameters and number of neighbours for Inverse Distance Weighting (IDW) interpolation using the `mapply` command and the `gstat` package in R. The optimal parameters are determined through the leave-one-out cross validation. Until now what I have used for the meuse dataset is the following; for 3 to 10 number of neighbours and for 2 to 5 power:

```
list_of_idw_results = mapply(idw, nmax = 3:10, idp = 2:5, 
                         MoreArgs = list(formula = zinc ~ 1, 
                                         data = meuse, 
                                         newdata = meuse.grid))
```